# Why is toString in class A evoked even though it is not called?

Tags: java, string, class, tostring

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object a1 = new A();
        Object a2 = new Object();
        System.out.println(a1);
        System.out.println(a2);
    }
}

class A {
    int x;

    public String toString() {
        return "A's x is " + x;
    }
}
```

*Output*

> A's x is 0
>
> java.lang.Object@1edf1c96

When a1 is printed, the `toString()` method inside class A is called without being explicitly called. Can you please explain to me how that happens.

Comment: What else is `println` supposed to print?

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` is implicitly called by `println(Object)`. Obviously, because it needs to display a `String`, and `toString()` is guaranteed to return **some** form of `String` representation for all objects.

Comment: can  you please explain how that happens. How does the compiler know that the the toString method in class A will return a string?

Comment: Because that's how it's defined in `Object.toString()`.

Comment: @Enzio: because that is defined by its type. Why do you think you write `public String toString() {`... Because you have a contract it returns a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the documentation of [`PrintStream.println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)):

> **`public void println(Object x)`**
>
> Print an Object and then terminate the line. This
>   method behaves as though it **invokes `print(Object)`** and then
>   `println()`.
>
> Parameters:
>         `x` - The Object to be printed.

Now if we take a look at [`PrintStream.print(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.Object)), we see:

> **`public void print(Object obj)`**
>
> Print an object. The string **produced by the
>   `String.valueOf(Object)`** method is translated into bytes according to
>   the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written
>   in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.
>
> Parameters:
>         `obj` - The Object to be printed

Now as you can see, internally the [`String.valueOf(object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) is called, which is defined as:

> **`public static String valueOf(Object obj)`**
>
> Returns the string representation of the Object
>   argument.
>
> Parameters:
>         `obj` - an Object.
>      Returns:
>        if
>   the argument is `null`, then a string equal to `"null"`; **otherwise,
>   the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.**

So that means that if you write something like:

```
System.out.println(foo);
```

You actually have written something *equivalent* to:

```
System.out.print(foo);
System.out.println();
```

which expand further into:

```
System.out.print(String.valueOf(foo));
System.out.println();
```

which expands into:

```
if(foo == null) {
    System.out.print("null");
} else {
    System.out.print(foo.toString());
}
System.out.println();
```

Or to make it more clear. In the code of `PrintStream`, you will see something like:

```
public class PrintStream {

    // ...

    public void println(Object x) {
        this.print(x);
        this.println();
    }

    public void print(Object obj) {
        String result = String.valueOf(obj);
        // ... do something with result (print it to the stream)
    }

}
```

and in `String` you will find something like:

```
public class String {

    // ...

    public static String valueOf (Object obj) {
        if(obj == null) {
            return "null";
        } else {
            return obj.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` method is defined in every `Object`. Its default behavior is to return a string representation of that object like `"java.lang.Object@1edf1c96"`.

In your `A` class you just replaced this behavior with a new one, by redefining the `toString()` method ("redefining" means defining that method again in a subclass using the same signature).

This is called **Override**.

When you print an object, the `println()` method will blindly call the `toString()` method of the object, without knowing (or caring) if it was redefined or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to represent any object as a string, `toString()` method comes into existence.

The `toString()` method returns the string representation of the object.

If you print any object, java compiler internally invokes the `toString()` method on the object. So overriding the `toString()` method, returns the desired output, it can be the state of an object etc. depends on your implementation.
By overriding the `toString()` method of the `Object` class, we can return values of the object, so we don't need to write much code.